# Detect gaps between dates in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, gaps-and-islands

I have a SQLite table with the following structure:

[image]

As you can see the `sampleDate` column has a new row every 1 minute, but sometimes the process stops and there are "time gaps" as in the underlined example. I need to find these gaps with a `SQL` query as this table is huge.

A posible expected result output could be:

```
2023-03-20 12:56:27
2023-03-29 10:46:46
```

This could represent that there is a gap between these two dates.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include some simple data as **text** and the expected output ?

Comment: @SelVazi, sure already added!

Comment: Please write in english only !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEAD()` function to retrieve the next date then calculate the difference to retrieve gaps :

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
          lead(sampleDate, 1, sampleDate) over (order by sampleDate) as nextDate,
          CAST(strftime('%M', lead(sampleDate, 1, sampleDate) over (order by sampleDate)) as integer) 
          - CAST(strftime('%M', sampleDate) as integer) as diff
  from mytable
)
select sampleDate, nextDate
from cte
where diff > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or could you use a left anti-join to get the rows where there is no next minute record ? Example provided below -

```
with cte as (
  select 4556 id, datetime('2023-03-20 12:54:27') sampleDate
  union ALL
  select 4557 id, datetime('2023-03-20 12:55:27') sampleDate
  union ALL
  select 4558 id, datetime('2023-03-20 12:56:27') sampleDate
  union ALL
  select 4559 id, datetime('2023-03-29 10:46:46') sampleDate
  union ALL
  select 4560 id, datetime('2023-10-06 10:52:47') sampleDate
  union ALL
  select 4561 id, datetime('2023-10-06 10:53:47') sampleDate
 )
 select a.* from cte a 
 left join cte b ON  b.sampledate = datetime(a.sampleDate,'+1 minutes') -- if wanted the gap to be exact one minutes
            --  ON b.sampledate between datetime(a.sampleDate,'+1 seconds')  and datetime(a.sampleDate,'+1 minutes')  -- if you wanted the gap to be anywhere under a minute
 where b.id is NULL
```